# Filter dict by certain values

Tags: python, dictionary, filtering

I have a dict that looks like this

```
db = {
'ObjectID': ['-1', '6', '10', '13', '13', '13', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1'], 
'Test_value': ['25', '0,28999999', '100,00000000', 'Geometry', '126641,847400000000', '473106,185600000030', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], 
'Has_error': ['true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false'], 
'Message': ['Table row counts are different', 'ObjectID 6 is different for Field DIKTE_BRUGDEK', 'ObjectID 10 is different for Field RICHTING_1',                'ObjectID 13 is different for Field GEOMETRIE', 'ObjectID 13 is different for Field X', 'ObjectID 13 is different for Field Y', 'Shape types are the          same', 'Feature types are the same', 'Feature class extents are the same', 'GeometryDefs are the same', 'Field properties are the same', 'Spatial             references are the same'], 'Identifier': ['Table', 'FeatureClass', 'FeatureClass', 'FeatureClass', 'FeatureClass', 'FeatureClass', 'FeatureClass',            'FeatureClass', 'FeatureClass', 'GeometryDef', 'Field', 'SpatialReference'], 
'Base_value': ['23', '0,19000000', '394,00000000', 'Geometry', '126530,700000000000', '473095,700000000010', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']}
```

I want to to break it down into a smaller subset based on the entries in the list of 'ObjectID', namely -1. 
My first attempt was to built an index of the values, like:

```
filter_ind = []
for k,v in db.iteritems():
    for i in xrange(len(v)):
            if (k == 'ObjectID') and (int(v[i]) != -1):
                filter_ind.append(i)
```

Then I tried to build a new dict, using filter_ind as a sort filter: 
    `dict((k,v[i]) for i in filter_ind for k, v in db.iteritems())`

What I get is only the last match as `v` isn't a list anymore:
`{'ObjectID':'13','Test_value':'473106,185600000030','Has_error':'true',
    'Message':'ObjectID 13 is different for Field Y',
    'Identifier':'FeatureClass','Base_value': '473095,700000000010'}`

Question: is there another way to filter a dict based on certain value within itself? If this is considered a relatively straigh forward approach, what is a smart way to use the index as filter to create a new dict? Thanks already.

Comment: As I said, the value lists should contain only entries based on the index of `db ['ObjectID'] != -1` (which is  `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: Thanks, my original interpretation was that you wanted a list of dicts, something like `[{'ObjectID': '6', ...}, {'ObjectID': '10', ...}, ...]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this a bit. First, there's no need for the nested loops. You can get the indices you want this way:

```
oids = db['ObjectID']
for i, id in enumerate(oids):
    if id != -1
        filter_ind.append(i)
```

Or more tersely,

```
filter_ind = [i for i, id in enumerate(oids) if id != '-1']
```

Then you could use the ids to filter the individual lists:

```
dict((key, [val[i] for i in filter_ind]) for key, val in db.iteritems())
```

Comment: Had the same impression...:-/ This is very straight forward. Thanks!

Comment: @larsvegas, I'll add, briefly, that this is a somewhat unconventional dictionary. Have you considered structuring it as a dictionary of dictionaries using `id` as the major key and the filed names as keys to the inner dictionaries?

Comment: haven't considered it yet, no...I just read the data like this from a dbf, so I wanted to keep the column, row structure intact.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I cooked up:

```
new_db=db.copy()
fltr=[x=='-1' for x in new_db['ObjectID']] #Not actually necessary, but makes the code a little more readable

for k,v in new_db.items():
    new_db[k]=[x for i,x in enumerate(new_db[k]) if fltr[i]]  #replace old lists with new filtered ones.
```

This is very similar to the answer posted by senderle (I think).  I use a boolean list whereas the other answer uses the indices.  Mine's probably not as efficient, but it's easier for me to read/understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
from operator import itemgetter

iget = itemgetter(*(i for i, id in enumerate(db['ObjectID']) if int(id) != -1))
result = dict((k, list(iget(v))) for k, v in db.items())
```

Comment: I guess this is the advanced option, it is less readable for me at least. What is the `*`-operator doing here? Is it an operator?

Comment: The `*` here is sometimes called the splat operator, it is called [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the documentation.  Basically `foo(*[1, 2, 3])` is equivalent to `foo(1, 2, 3)`.  The [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function accepts any number of indices (or keys) and returns a function that can be used to filter sequences (or mappings) to only grab the specified elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2.7:

```
from itertools import compress
indexes = [(x != -1) for x in db['ObjectID']]
result = dict((k, compress(v, indexes)) for k, v in db.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a rare occasion where you can use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress

sels = [x != '-1' for x in db['ObjectID']]
comp = {key: list(compress(vals, sels)) for key, vals in db.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this one:

```
[dict(zip(db.keys(),e)) for e in zip(*db.values()) if e[0]!='-1']
```

It returns a list of dicts excluding the one with -1.